# How to use a Visual Studio static library from mingw-w64?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, mingw-w64

The title is pretty self explanatory: I need to call functions (they are `extern "C"` so no mangling) in a Visual Studio 2019 `.lib` file from a mingw-w64 `.exe`; I have the source code for both. The reason is that I'm writing a 3D game with 2 renderers: OpenGL and Direct3D 11, and the core code and the OpenGL renderer are compiled with mingw-w64, but the D3D11 part is compiled with VS. How to interoperate between them? Can I merge both renderers into one `.a` (mingw-w64) static library or one `.dll` and call it from mingw-w64, or should I make a separate `.dll` for D3D and use its functions as needed?

---

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56728061/7616532) about a way to avoid data races across `std` implementations. I decided to link it because both questions are about the same program that I'm writing.

Comment: To avoid incompatibilities, better use a DLL.

Comment: It would really be better if you compiled your whole application with the same compiler. D3D apps can be compiled with MingW, and OpenGL apps can be compiled under Visual Studio.

Comment: @NicolBolas Compiling whole under mingw-w64 is preferrable, but unfortunately almost impossible, since DirectX SDK heavily uses Microsoft-specific extensions.