# Mutex that works across std implementations

Tags: c++, mutex

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56727833/7616532), I need a mutex that works across `std` implementations, or a way to atomically write and read a pointer. One thread is spawned by code compiled with mingw-w64 and the other one is Visual Studio 2019 code in a static/dynamic library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export from your main executable (mingw-w64) to your DLL (VC++) - compiled with separate compilers - a synchronization/mutex "handle" (an opaque pointer, typically, though it can be an index into something too) and a pair of C-style functions (if you want, you can wrap them into classes like `std::mutex` and `std::lock`, exposing the same API - that'd be the safest thing to do) lock and unlock that take that handle.  They can be just as bare as that, or they might include additional functionality like timeout, or try-lock - these are quite useful but not required.  You can also export `handle_t create()` and `void delete(handle_t handle)` functions.

The point is that the sync object itself (the mutex or whatever) is always manipulated by those indirection functions to avoid errors in usage, and these functions are, depending on the compiler (that can easily be detected by the preprocessor), backed by compiler-specific atomic operation intrinsics or CRT functions, like the perfectly fitting [`InterlockedCompareExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange) (it works under mingw-w64 too) and its Visual C++ specific [compiler intrinsic variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ttk2z1ws(v=vs.85)), or GCC's [`__atomic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) (more specifically, `__atomic_compare_exchange`).

Comment: So the question now is: how do I atomically write or read in C++?

Comment: @VladislavToncharov - is that a separate question or is that something you're asking because you think my answer above requires it in some way?

Comment: It'd be nice if your answer included a code example of atomic writing and reading a pointer from C++, that way it'd be 100% comprehensive in my case.

Comment: @VladislavToncharov - that's a different question completely unrelated to how to get a mutex that works across std implementations.  And unnecessary to apply the answer above.  But if you want, look up std::atomic at cppreference (or the C++ guide of your choice).

Comment: `std::atomic` is the exact thing I can't use. It's most certainly ABI-incompatible between VS and mingw-w64. I need a way to atomically write or read a location in C++ without `std` (that's what my question asks) and that really would fit into your answer.

Comment: @VladislavToncharov - Your question asks for a mutex that can be shared, and that's what I answered.  It also asks for a way to atomically read and write a pointer, which I assumed you were doing with a mutex.  So, do your atomic pointer operations under a mutex shared as I outline above and you're done.  But since, per your other question, you're using Direct3D and thus are using Windows - just use the Windows Interlocked* APIs to roll your own atomic, just like we all did before C++11.

Comment: Okay, I edited your answer to also provide the atomic operation reference for both compilers.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct imutex {
  virtual void lock() = 0;
  virtual void unlock() = 0;
  virtual ~imutex(){}
};
template<class M>
struct imp_mutex: imutex {
  M m;
  void lock() final override { m.lock(); }
  void unlock() final override { m.unlock(); }
};

struct mymutex {
  using up=std::unique_ptr<imutex, void(*)(imutex*)>;
  mymutex( up m_in ):m(std::move(m_in)){}
  mymutex():mymutex(up(new imp_mutex<std::mutex>{}, [](imutex* m){ delete m; })) {}
  void lock(){ m->lock(); }
  void unlock(){ m->unlock(); }
  mymutex(mymutex&&)=delete;
private:
  up m;
};
```

this assumes ABI compatibility of vtables and std::unique_ptr, which is plausible.

If not, replace unique ptr with something custom, and replace the virtual methods with function pointers taking a void pointer.

The point is, the mutex is created and destroyed in one library's code.

Here is a pure function pointer one.  It relies that a struct containing two-three ptrs has the same layout, and that thr C calling convention is the same.

Whichever library makes the mymutex, both can then use it.

```
struct imutex_vtable {
  void (*lock)(void*) = 0;
  void (*unlock)(void*) = 0;
  void (*dtor)(void*)=0;
};
template<class M>
imutex_vtable const* get_imutex_vtable(){
  static const imutex_vtable vtable = {
    [](void* m){ static_cast<M*>(m)->lock(); },
    [](void* m){ static_cast<M*>(m)->unlock(); },
    [](void* m){ delete static_cast<M*>(m); }
  };
  return &vtable;
}

struct mymutex {
  mymutex( imutex_vtable const* vt, void* pm ):vtable(vt), pv(pm){}
  template<class M>
  explicit mymutex(std::unique_ptr<M> m):mymutex( get_imutex_vtable<M>(), m.release() ) {}
  mymutex():mymutex(std::make_unique<std::mutex>()) {}
  void lock(){ vtable->lock(pv); }
  void unlock(){ vtable->unlock(pv); }
  ~mymutex(){ vtable->dtor(pv); }
  mymutex(mymutex&&)=delete;
private:
  imutex_vtable const* vtable=0;
  void* pv=0;
};
```

This is basically implementing a simple case of C++ interface inheritance using C-like implementation, then wrapping it up in classes and templates so the user won't notice.

Comment: It may be _plausible_ that there is ABI compatibility of vtables and std::unique_ptr between different compilation systems - but how can you _count_ on it? Agner Fog [in his great document on Calling Conventions](https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) details the many ways in which this assumption is incorrect.  So, really, it isn't plausible at all.

Comment: @david they have specific compilers.  They can **check**.  And if they have incompatible calling conventions all the way down to C they are doomed.  If they have compatible vtables and unique ptr, they can use the above.  If they have compatible C struct layout and C function pointer calling convention, I described a solution.